# Multiplication with multiple summations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have function
$$F(m,x)=1-\sum _{k=0}^{m-1}\sum _{t=0}^{k}g(m,k,t,x)h(m,k,t,x)$$
Is it possible to write 
$$G(m,x)=F(m_1,x)F(m_2,x)$$
in compact/simplified form (probably with two summation indices)? I am looking for a general solution.

Or is it impossible to write without knowing exact expressions of $g(m,k,t,x)$ and $h(m,k,t,x)$?

Comment: According to what you wrote, $F(m,x)=1-\frac12 m(m-1) g(m,n,x)h(m,n,x)$. Or did you mean for $t$ and/or $k$ to somehow occur inside the expression you're summing?

Comment: Yes, Thanks !!! I will modify the question.

Comment: In that case I doubt it can be simplified in the case where $m_1\neq m_2$. The product then is dependent on $\frac12 m_1(m_1-1) + \frac12 m_2(m_2-1)$ values of $g(m,k,t,x)h(m,k,t,x)$, each of which has a different list of input variables--hence you could change the result by changing the value of either $g(m,k,t,x)$ or $h(m,k,t,x)$ at any one of those points independently. Hence all $\frac12 m_1(m_1-1) + \frac12 m_2(m_2-1)$ of those terms have to remain listed in the formula; the summation notation seems the most convenient way to do so.